# How to make the cups client.conf file optional?

Tags: ubuntu, cups

In order to print when I'm at the office, I need to add a file `/etc/cups/client.conf` with content

```
ServerName our.cups.server/version=1.1
```

However, when I get home, the existence of this file makes Ubuntu 20.04 freeze when I log in to the graphical interface. So what I have been doing, as a workaround, is either deleting the file before going home, or logging in through a terminal, deleting the file, and only then logging in to the graphical interface.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? For example, is there a way to tell cups to ignore the file if it cannot connect?

Comment: No, but, as part of system startup, after the system knows "home" or "work" (check "`arp -an`" or `ip route`), you can create or delete the file.

Comment: Always delete the `/etc/cups/client.conf` file at system startup. If you're at work, create the file and `service cups restart`